# Count how many vowels are in a string, excluding repetitions using for loop python

Tags: python

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
s = 'abcabcde'
count = 0

for letter in s:
    if letter in 'aeiou':
        count += 1

print ('Number of vowels: ' + str(count))
```

Comment: Give it a go first, if you're struggling, then ask a question with code snippets.

Comment: You should provide the example of what you want the count to return.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
vowels = set(['a','e','i','o','u'])
s = 'abcabcde'
set_s = set(s)
print ('Number of vowels: ' + str(len(vowels & set_s)))
```

Gives

2

Comment: If you're using **`set`** why not use [**`set.intersection`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)?

Comment: @PeterWood Sorry I gave answer for vowels not in string.

Answer (score 1):

For an explicit loop-based solution, you can do the following:

```
seen = set()
s = 'abcabcde'
for c in s:
    if c in 'aeiou':
        seen.add(c)
print ('Number of vowels: ' + len(seen))
```

Or more concisely, using set intersection:

```
count = len(set('aeiou') & set('abcabcde'))
```

Answer (score 0):

vcount = lambda txt: sum([1  for i in 'aeiou' if i in txt])

print(vcount('fox'), vcount('eating')
 1 3